# How do I make an image inside a WP7 Pivot TitleTemplate invisible?

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot, visibility, itemtemplate

I'm working on a WP7 app and when the user rotates to landscape, i'd like to hide an image within the header of the app so the user can see more information.

At the moment, I have the image inside the TitleTemplate of a Pivot control. Using Blend i added a VisualState called "Land" for when it's in Landscape mode and I hide the image. This looks fine in Blend. When i run it through Visual Studio, the image just never disappears!

My XAML and associated c# are as follows. Using an example i found, i derive the name of the VisualState to use based on the first 4 characters of the Orientation value.

```
 <controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image x:Name="headerImage" Visibility="Visible"  Source="{StaticResource headerLogo}"  Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Land">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="headerImage">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Port"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Image>   
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
```

And the associated C# - which i've stepped into in the debugger (so it's getting hit)

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, e.Orientation.ToString().Substring(0,4), false);            
    }
```

Can anyone see any howlers?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged( object sender,  
  OrientationChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
  PageOrientation orientation = e.Orientation; 

    if ((orientation & PageOrientation.Landscape) == PageOrientation.Landscape) 
    { 
        headerImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        //Set height of grid to auto
     } 
     else if ((orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait)== PageOrientation.Portrait) 
     { 
        headerImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     } 
}
```

[This](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/140836/handling-page-orientation-in-windows-phone-7/) tutorial might also aid you in understanding. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response - however, this tutorial doesn't look to address changing the contents within a TitleTemplate. I don't think the code example you have provided would work as the headerImage control exists within a template and wouldn't be accessible at that point in code. (but i may be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I've always followed [this tutorial](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2011/03/08/handling-wp7-orientation-changes-via-visual-states.aspx) to handle it, so you can do all layouting inside Blend and don't need to code anything in the OrientationChanged itself.

Comment: This was interesting and useful - but didn't it directly solve my problem though. I've still used the code, but i had to move my headerImage into a UserControl then attach the new Behavor inside the userControl. This works, but it doesn't seem quite right. Would think it would be better to have the Behaviour outside the UserControl, but that didn't work. Thanks!